# Writing a program in C# where depending on the Id (txtBxNumber) it will either update or create a new record in a text file and a Rich Text Box

Tags: c#, winforms, io

```cs
   fileName = txtBxFileNamePath.Text;

            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                if (txtBxDate.Text != null && txtBxNumber.Text != null && txtBxUnit.Text != null && txtBxUnitPrice.Text != null && txtBxShipTo.Text != null
                      && txtBxOrdered.Text != null && richTxBxDesc.Text != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int higherThanZero = Int32.Parse(txtBxNumber.Text);

                        if (higherThanZero > 0)
                        {
                            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(fileName))
                            {
                                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
                                
                                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length - 1; i++)
                                {
                                    string firstNum = lines[i].Substring(0, 2);

                                    if (firstNum == txtBxNumber.Text)
                                    {
                                        string record = "hello ";
                                        lines[i].Replace(lines[i], record);
                                    }

                                    else
                                    {


                                        int orderNum = Int32.Parse(txtBxOrdered.Text);
                                        int unitPriceNum = Int32.Parse(txtBxUnitPrice.Text);
                                        double tax = .13;
                                        int taxInt = (int)tax;
                                        int amount = orderNum * unitPriceNum;
                                        string amountStr = amount.ToString();
                                        int amountTotal = amount * taxInt;
                                        string amountTotalStr = amountTotal.ToString();
                                        amountList.Add(amountStr);
                                        amountTotalList.Add(amountTotalStr);

                                        string record = amountTotalStr.PadRight(30) + amountStr.PadRight(30);
                                        richTxtBxRecord.Text += record + "\n";

                                        using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
                                        {
                                            write.WriteLine(record + "\n");

                                            write.Close();
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            richTxtBxError.Text += "Textbox Number must contain a digit higher than 0 ";
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        richTxtBxError.Text += "Please make sure number text box is a digit"; 
                    }

                    
                }

                else
                {
                    richTxtBxError.Text += "please make sure that no text boxes are empty";
                }      
            }

            else
            {
                richTxtBxError.Text += "Please select a file that already exists";
            }
```

I am having an issue where once i get past the try-catch statement "please make sure number is a digit, no code executes. I am trying to obtain the first few characters in a text file and match it with the users input. If the input is the same as what is already inserted in the text file, i update the whole record. If there is no match (non existent number) i write in a brand new record.

Comment: I would start by using "early exit" to simplify your `if` ladder.  For example, the first `if` could simply be `if (!File.Exists(fileName)) return;`

Comment: @RobertHarvey This is a Nasty nesting pattern

Comment: I need to display an error message one way or another. In reality they all have to be posted at the same time

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to do that by nesting `if` statements.  Get all of your validation done up front.  You can then focus on the actual code to be executed.

Comment: Don't use `int.Parse`, use `int.TryParse`.  Consider how much cleaner your code would be if it said `if (!int.TryParse(txtBxNumber.Text, out var numberVal) || numberVal <= 0) {rtbError.Text += "Please make sure you enter a number greater than 0"; return; }`.  A lot of your code complexity would fall away

Comment: If you throw an exception, it's going to kick you out of that loop.  You can see that, right?  If you want your loop to continue executing after an exception is thrown, you have to put the `catch` block **inside the loop.**

Comment: Your code is *very* complicated.  Start by getting rid of all the try/catch and else stuff - test all your pre-conditions before you start, if any of them fail, return (or do whatever else it is that you do after the final `else`).  Then, make your StreamReader code only a few lines long (you just read everything into an array - then you're done).  Then repost your code.  Then, in V2 of your question, clearly describe what you are trying to do.  I suspect by that point, your code may be readable, but giving us hints is a good idea too

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite follow your logic, but I tried.  You should be able to take this code and do what you want (whatever it is).

I started by declaring some class level variables.

```
private DateTime _dateValue;
private int _numberValue;
private decimal _unitPrice;
private int _numberOrdered;
```

Then, since you have so many preconditions and so many text boxes, I factored out the validation and setting of these variables.  It makes the logic (whatever it supposed to be) much easier to follow:

```
private bool ValidateUserEntry()
{
    bool isError = false;
    if (!File.Exists(txtBxFileNamePath.Text))
    {
        AddError("File Name must exist");
        isError = true;
    }

    if (txtBxDate.Text == string.Empty || !DateTime.TryParse(txtBxDate.Text, out var _dateValue))
    {
        AddError("The date must be a valid date");
        isError = true;
    }

    if (txtBxNumber.Text == string.Empty || !int.TryParse(txtBxNumber.Text, out _numberValue) ||
        _numberValue <= 0)
    {
        AddError("You must enter a number greater than 0 for [Number]");
        isError = true;
    }

    if (txtBxUnitPrice.Text == string.Empty || !decimal.TryParse(txtBxUnitPrice.Text, out _unitPrice) ||
        _unitPrice <= 0.0m)
    {
        AddError("The unit price must be a positive decimal number");
        isError = true;
    }

    if (txtBxShipTo.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        AddError("A ship to address is required");
        isError = true;
    }

    if (txtBxOrdered.Text == string.Empty || !int.TryParse(txtBxOrdered.Text, out _numberOrdered) ||
        _numberOrdered <= 0)
    {
        AddError("The Number ordered must be a number greater than 0");
        isError = true;
    }

    if (richTxBxDesc.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        AddError("A description is required");
        isError = true;
    }

    return !isError;
}
```

I also added two utility functions for managing the error list:

```
private void ClearError()
{
    richTxtBxError.Text = string.Empty;
}

private void AddError(string errorMessage)
{
    richTxtBxError.Text += (errorMessage + Environment.NewLine);
    richTxtBxError.SelectionStart = richTxtBxError.Text.Length;
    richTxtBxError.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

Now comes the real code.  Near as I can tell, you want to scan a text file.  If the number in the first few character positions matches a number in your input, then you change the line to some constant text.  Otherwise, you want to do a calculation and put the results of the calculation on the line of text.

My input file looks like this:

```
1  First
2  Second
3  Third
12 Twelth
13 Thirteenth
34 Thirty-fourth
```

and the code that I run looks like what's below.  The logic makes no sense, but it was what I could discern from your code.  Instead of trying to do things on the fly to a file (which never really turns out well unless you are *really* careful), I gather the output into a `List<string>`.  Once I have all the output, I put it in a text box control and overwrite the file.

```
ClearError();
//check pre-conditions
if (!ValidateUserEntry())
{
    return;
}

string[] lines;
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(txtBxFileNamePath.Text))
{
    lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtBxFileNamePath.Text);
}


List<string> newLines = new List<string>();

for (var lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < lines.Length; ++lineIndex)
{
    var line = lines[lineIndex];
    if (line.Length > 2 && int.TryParse(line.Substring(0, 2), out var linePrefixNumber) &&
        linePrefixNumber == _numberValue)
    {
        newLines.Add("Bingo, hit the right record");
    }
    else
    {
        decimal tax = .13m;
        var amount = _numberOrdered * _unitPrice;
        var amountTotal = amount * (1m + tax);
        //amountList.Add(amount.TosString());
        //amountTotalList.Add(amountTotal.ToString());

        var newRecord = $"{amountTotal,30:C}{amount,30:C}";
        newLines.Add(newRecord);    //every record but one will be the same, but, such is life

    }
}

//at this point, the newLines list has what I want
//put it in the text box
richTxtBxRecord.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, newLines);

//and write it out
using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(txtBxFileNamePath.Text, append:false))
{
    write.Write(richTxtBxRecord.Text);
    write.Flush();
}
```

With inputs that look like:

```
Number:          12
Number Ordered:  3
Unit Price:      1.23
```

The output (oddly enough - but it's what I could figure from your code) looks like:

```
                         $4.17                         $3.69
                         $4.17                         $3.69
                         $4.17                         $3.69
Bingo, hit the right record
                         $4.17                         $3.69
                         $4.17                         $3.69
```

You can see that the input line that had the 12 at the start gets switched for bingo. The rest get the same information.  I'm sure that's not what you want.  But, with this code, you should be able to get something that you'd like.

Also note that I treat all the currency values as `decimal` (not `int` or `double`).  For the life of me, I have no idea what you were trying to do with the `taxInt` variable (it will always be zero the way you have coded it).  Instead, I did a rational tax calculation.

Comment: @jordan: By the way, if this is a very large file, don't read it all into memory at once. Instead, open the original file for read and a second file for write. Read a line, decide what you want to do and write 0, 1 or more lines as a result into the temp file. Once you finish, close both files, delete the original file and then rename the temp file to match the original one.

Answer (score -1):

All of the code below the catch block is inside an else block, so I wouldn't expect it to execute. If you want something to execute after the catch, remove it from the else block.

Comment: The only code below the `catch` block is error messages.

Comment: This is a comment, it doesn't really answer the question - not that it's really obvious what that question is

Comment: You have sufficient rep to post actual comments.

Comment: Well, he said once he gets past the catch block nothing executes. I'm not sure what he expects to execute after the catch block.

Comment: It sounds like his question is why isn't anything executing beyond the catch block.